# NGINX TCP TLS termination with client authentication

Tags: java, ssl, nginx, tcp

- **Rationale :**

I'm having the case when the server side (backing service) can not provide authorisation/authentication layer.

- **Approach:**

I'm trying to hide behing the nginx and thus to achieve a client-server mutual authorisation (from java client to nginx)
java client <-(ssl,certificates)->nginx:8102<-(open tcp)->backing service:18102
For simplification nginx and backing service reside on one VM.

To achieve that I followed the tutorial :
http://nategood.com/client-side-certificate-authentication-in-ngi
I have generated ca,client,server keys,certificates as follows
(the server certificate is self signed)

I also have created some nginx set up:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log .../error.log debug;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
stream {
  upstream stream_backend {
    server localhost:18102;
  }
  server {
    listen                8102 ssl;
    proxy_pass            stream_backend;
    ssl_certificate        .../server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    .../server.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate .../ca.crt;
    ssl_client_certificate .../client.crt;
    ssl_verify_depth 1;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    #ssl_protocols          TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #ssl_ciphers           HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #ssl_ciphers "AES256-SHA:SHA512withECDSA";
    #ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
    #ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout   4h;
    ssl_handshake_timeout 30s;
  }
}
```

Then i was able to autorise using open ssl

```
openssl s_client -cert client.crt -key client.key -debug -connect <nginxhost>:8102
```

So far so good.

- **The issue:**

Then i followed to integrate it with JVM client

I generated the password protected PKCS12 file for client.crt

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.crt -inkey client.key  -out client.p12
```

and also was trying to generate the pkcs12 file for all combination of certificates (using the trick with trust store)

```
keytool -import -file ca.crt -alias ca -keystore trust-store
keytool -import -file server.crt -alias server -keystore trust-store;
keytool -import -file client.crt -alias client -keystore trust-store;
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore trust-store -destkeystore client.p12  -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass <anygiven passwd>
```

, but was not able to properly autorize 
I run a plain Jedis client

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis(uri);//, sslSocketFactory, sslParameters, null);
jedis.set("foo", "bar");
System.out.println(">>>" + jedis.get("foo"));
jedis.disconnect();
jedis.close();
```

with options

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:record  -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake -Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=client.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<given>
```

What i get is :

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1498167495 bytes = { 191, 197, 46, 4, 183, 146, 82, 209, 69, 135, 151, 205, 65, 55, 24, 150, 123, 60, 122, 226, 192, 23, 211, 254, 14, 59, 34, 244 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 167
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 89
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1537147415 bytes = { 45, 32, 242, 160, 72, 168, 116, 190, 65, 91, 130, 252, 92, 249, 244, 109, 101, 74, 162, 188, 255, 196, 148, 149, 17, 213, 198, 57 }
Session ID:  {57, 214, 187, 172, 64, 105, 42, 71, 106, 76, 50, 178, 51, 65, 243, 193, 201, 181, 197, 12, 180, 23, 43, 213, 228, 121, 240, 227, 68, 115, 112, 147}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed, ansiX962_compressed_prime, ansiX962_compressed_char2]
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
** TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 904
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=AU
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 148561064520149382265326610552347817946745543429726527079571023440869096298585266785042725149311452500913565526887156223039098472927158834345207963498945320440101735487342373095629935479052530558787124675414307741499494705584955553763604061463652853202297289153979489934006401951701144761964805588493413561041
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Jun 22 10:25:22 CEST 2017,
               To: Fri Jun 22 10:25:22 CEST 2018]
  Issuer: O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=AU
  SerialNumber: [    01]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 78 C2 25 5D EE 44 50 1D   E1 77 5A EB 3F D7 A6 E6  x.%].DP..wZ.?...
0010: 55 08 C8 C2 E2 24 44 B7   D8 AE 35 51 CA 93 2E CE  U....$D...5Q....
..
01E0: B5 89 B4 A6 9E 2F B4 C6   37 5A CE 0A D3 39 B7 D4  ...../..7Z...9..
01F0: CC 6A 9A B5 46 05 B8 17   89 29 90 DB DC 9E B5 B9  .j..F....)......

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=AU
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 148561064520149382265326610552347817946745543429726527079571023440869096298585266785042725149311452500913565526887156223039098472927158834345207963498945320440101735487342373095629935479052530558787124675414307741499494705584955553763604061463652853202297289153979489934006401951701144761964805588493413561041
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Jun 22 10:25:22 CEST 2017,
               To: Fri Jun 22 10:25:22 CEST 2018]
  Issuer: O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=AU
  SerialNumber: [    01]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 78 C2 25 5D EE 44 50 1D   E1 77 5A EB 3F D7 A6 E6  x.%].DP..wZ.?...
0010: 55 08 C8 C2 E2 24 44 B7   D8 AE 35 51 CA 93 2E CE  U....$D...5Q....
..
01E0: B5 89 B4 A6 9E 2F B4 C6   37 5A CE 0A D3 39 B7 D4  ...../..7Z...9..
01F0: CC 6A 9A B5 46 05 B8 17   89 29 90 DB DC 9E B5 B9  .j..F....)......
]
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 205
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA512withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 99646631278318376795489495527453257751498300731056420595286629015741962063348
  public y coord: 4942359814115858826459478922742110932389912636636308073122086926577854097688
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 119
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2), SHA512withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=AU>
*** ServerHelloDone
Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client authentication
*** Certificate chain
<Empty>
***
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
ECDH Public value:  { 4, 146, 247, 118, 74, 204, 87, 229, 88, 182, 122, 231, 203, 29, 89, 160, 251, 221, 92, 20, 67, 20, 70, 198, 21, 216, 245, 102, 33, 84, 141, 27, 247, 73, 120, 165, 200, 203, 98, 156, 155, 30, 127, 40, 106, 229, 240, 129, 59, 146, 14, 168, 195, 233, 43, 25, 55, 206, 24, 255, 17, 172, 230, 42, 212 }
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 77
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: A7 B2 BA B4 E7 4B 06 7E   B5 DB E9 8C C1 C6 57 AF  .....K........W.
0010: C2 45 88 D5 AF 27 25 BF   DB 25 07 9C 53 FE 8A 06  .E...'%..%..S...
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 59 4C 39 C7 BF C5 2E 04   B7 92 52 D1 45 87 97 CD  YL9.......R.E...
0010: 41 37 18 96 7B 3C 7A E2   C0 17 D3 FE 0E 3B 22 F4  A7...<z......;".
Server Nonce:
0000: A4 61 FE E9 2D 20 F2 A0   48 A8 74 BE 41 5B 82 FC  .a..- ..H.t.A[..
0010: 5C F9 F4 6D 65 4A A2 BC   FF C4 94 95 11 D5 C6 39  \..meJ.........9
Master Secret:
0000: F7 CF EF 52 4B 1A 5C DB   FB 10 21 CE 08 CA 53 DF  ...RK.\...!...S.
0010: 4B FD 21 27 74 D3 48 ED   9B BF 69 FC F0 D9 C1 81  K.!'t.H...i.....
0020: C5 A1 8A 8E 97 F3 00 F0   40 2A CB F4 5D AC 8E 0F  ........@*..]...
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 4B FC 7A 6D 42 5F 3C 17   EC 7E 96 49 16 FE 48 FD  K.zmB_<....I..H.
0010: A5 E9 12 A3 D8 9C A1 7C   0A 83 3A CF 38 40 11 1D  ..........:.8@..
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 19 22 CE 9A 44 28 25 DF   7B 7D EF C7 8E CC 02 8D  ."..D(%.........
0010: DB 65 62 70 B6 32 C2 05   96 A5 9E 2A DA A0 3F 2D  .ebp.2.....*..?-
Client write key:
0000: 3F AB B7 73 AD 71 BF 69   62 C6 5E D0 5B 41 BA 59  ?..s.q.ib.^.[A.Y
Server write key:
0000: 83 FF 63 92 F0 55 C0 E1   52 61 62 4C 52 08 C0 22  ..c..U..RabLR.."
... no IV derived for this protocol
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 83, 201, 118, 195, 61, 142, 225, 100, 14, 250, 36, 62 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 16, 123, 83, 171, 99, 243, 7, 153, 78, 213, 172, 252 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 80
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 64
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, close_notify
main, called closeInternal(false)
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 64
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
main, called closeSocket(false)
```

```

If I'm not mistaken the server can't find matching certificate (among its known client certificate) for given client certificate ?

Comment: The tutorial calls for a client CA. The value of `ssl_client_certificate` is a CA not the client's certificate. You need to sign the client certificate with the client CA. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Hi Richard the value is actually like that  - at least in nginx (server side)
     
_ssl_client_certificate .../client.crt;_

Comment: So what is `ca.crt` then?

Comment: The ca.crt is the 'so called' certify authority certificate - in this particular case this was self-signed cert  generated as 

 `openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 4096`
 `openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was on the client side.

When I creates the *PKCS#12* file for *client key,client cert*

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out client.p12 -inkey client.key -in client.crt
```

and then imported it into *trust store*

```
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore ts-stage.jks -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass <the same as above, truststore strong passwd>
```

together with server certificate

```
keytool -import -alias server -file server.crt -keystore ts-stage.jks -storepass <truststore strong passwd>
```

I was able to connect via JAVA client using *SSLSocketFactory*

```
private static SSLSocketFactory trustStoreWithClientPCKSAndServerCert() throws Exception {

    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jceks");
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream("ts-stage.jks");
        trustStore.load(inputStream, TRUST_STORE_PASSWD
                .toCharArray());
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }

    final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(trustStore, PKCS_PASSWD.toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
```